# How do I count number of cells based on a equality criteria =x, where x is a vector and not one number in excel?

Tags: excel

So, i have a set of numerical values for a variable, and i want to count the ones matching any one element of a given array.
In the image, the A column is the given vector i want to use as criteria, and count the ones in the K column, if they match any of the numbers in the column A

Screenshot of data:

[image]

Comment: You need to explain your problem more clearly.

Comment: you need to show us your effort in order to get help

Comment: Please check the screenshot i uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Add a new column, e.g. insert a new column L, with the header "In A?" and in L2 insert the formula:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(K2,$A:$A,0)),0,1)
```

This will return 1 if the value in column K appears somewhere in column A and 0 otherwise. 
Then, simply form the sum of this new column.